# Detecting built-in redefinition (False = True)

Tags: python

During a code review, I've stumbled up an interesting issue. As everything in Python is very dynamic, one can perform this:

```
False = True
if False:
    print "Yes please!"
```

Which behaves correctly and prints out `Yes please!`. While understanding the principles behind this behaviour, is there any automated code-checker that can detect such action?

I can always check presence of "False" in `locals()` or `globals()` or plethora of other ways for the same effect. While this may not be relevant for traditional software development, mistakes similar to his are sometimes seen in data analysis pipelines etc.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 this isn't allowed. You get a `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`

Comment: There's no point trying to detect this. Where would you draw the line? Are you going to try to detect every possible programming error?

Comment: any programmer who does this in production code or other than just to test if its possible should be fired on the spot ... that said any lint checker will probably catch something egregious like that ... try pylint

Comment: If all of the tests still pass, is this even an "error"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree - programmer should know better. However, there are automatic code-checking tools available and with me not having any extensive experience with them, I was wondering if any of them caught this.

Comment: @petr try pylint ... it will certainly warn you about shadowing builtins

Comment: @JoranBeasley I also agree with your comment - however, various biological pipelines and analysis glue can often be written by not-so-experienced programmers. (and then there are people like me who need to deal with such code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) does detect this, along with the redefinition of any built-in:

```
dan@dantop:~$ pylint h.py

No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module h
W:  1,0: Redefining built-in 'False'
```

**h.py:**

```
False = True
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for - will have a better look into pylint

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) to check for such assignments. It will show a warning.

```
W:  1, 0: Redefining built-in 'False' (redefined-builtin)
```